# Opera keeps prompting me to update Java- is this a virus?

Tags: browser, java, virus

Over the last few weeks, I've noticed that I keep getting prompted to update my Java at increasingly regular intervals. In the past, I have usually just gone ahead with this, but I am sure that it can't be the case that Java has been updated again almost every day...

I started using Opera because I found that Firefox and Chrome seemed to be getting quite slow...

Does anyone know anything about this? Have I got a virus? If so, can anyone recommend the best way to get rid of it? I have McAfee Total Protection installed on my computer, but this doesn't seem to have picked up any viruses...

I have had problems with browser hijacks in the past- where something has completely taken over my browser, so that I have some search engine that I've never heard of displaying results when I search for something rather than Google, which is my default search engine. Is this something similar?

Comment: goto java.com and download version 7 update 67 or higher and after it is done installing allow it to remove previous version.  After that if you are still plague by update notification it might be an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that this probably was a virus- similar to one I had that kept telling me that Flash Player was out of date any time I tried to watch video clips online. Having followed the advice of someone on SuperUser, I have stopped using McAfee as my antivirus, and am now using Avira instead- this has been much better at picking up/ removing any virus I get than McAfee ever was, and also seems to regularly inform me that it has blocked another potential threat.

Answer (score 1):

Well the real test is if [java's website](https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp) says you are on the latest version or not, and it is generally good advice to keep it updated to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's probably not. But to be sure, run a full virus scan, and check all your browser settings to see that they are normal.

I do recommend you follow the prompt and update your Java. Older Java versions have unfixed bugs and vulnerabilities that can harm your computer.

Comment: Faking a Java update is a clever way to get administrator privileges for your malware. There are known cases of faking Flash Player updates, so I'd be careful saying that it's probably not a virus.